# Vue 3 + Vite production output is not minified?

Tags: vue.js, vite

I made the switch from Vue CLI to Vite using the Vue plugin and I've just noticed that the output for my production build is not minified and is a total of 214kb. I have checked online for things to set in the configuration but nothing I've tried works in build options or rollup configuration options. I've read that apparently, minification is disabled for 'es' libs but I've even tried changing that to CommonJS and some other settings and it does not minify either and just produces an even larger output. Does anyone know how to get minification working on Vue 3 + Vite?

vite.config.js

```
import {defineConfig} from 'vite';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import * as path from 'path';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        vue({
            template: {
                compilerOptions: {
                    isCustomElement: (tag) => tag === 'lite-youtube'
                }
            }
        }),
    ],
    resolve: {
        mainFields: ['fesm2020', 'fesm2015', 'module'],
        alias: {
            '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src')
        }
    },
    build: {
        assetsInlineLimit: 0
    },
    server: {
        port: 8080
    },
});
```

Command used to build: `vite build`

Comment: we need your vite.config.js, package.json and what command you use to run the build

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev updated.